# Deploying Express app to Vercel gives errors

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

Running the server locally produces no problems, however when I deploy to Vercel I get the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'startsWith') at connectionStringHasValidScheme (/var/task/server/node_modules/mongodb-connection-string-url/lib/index.js:9:30) at new ConnectionString (/var/task/server/node_modules/mongodb-connection-string-url/lib/index.js:85:34) at parseOptions (/var/task/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/connection_string.js:201:17) at new MongoClient (/var/task/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:46:63) at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/server/db/conn.js:3:16) at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14) at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10) at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32) at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12) at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)`

I'm really not sure what the problem is - I've done a bit of googling but it hasn't produced many results for this issue (at least not that I found).

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const bp = require('body-parser');
require("dotenv").config({ path: "./db/config.env" });
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(require("./routes/auth"));
app.use(require("./routes/user"));
const dbo = require("./db/conn");

app.listen(port, () => {
  dbo.connectToServer(function (err) {
    if (err) console.error(err);

  });
  console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`);
});
```

conn.js

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
const Db = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
const client = new MongoClient(Db, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});
 
var _db;
 
module.exports = {
  connectToServer: function (callback) {
    client.connect(function (err, db) {
      // Verify we got a good "db" object
      if (db)
      {
        _db = db.db("preview");
        console.log("Successfully connected to MongoDB."); 
      }
      return callback(err);
         });
  },
 
  getDb: function () {
    return _db;
  },
};
```

I tried cutting the code down to a minimal just to figure out what component is causing the bug, unfortunately with no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you deploy your app to Vercel, you also need declare your environment variables in your project [settings page](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/environment-variables).

Go to the Environment Variables page of your Project Settings and define `ATLAS_URI` value. Note that you need to deploy your project again before new environment variables becomes available.